# Is Spring Cache clusterable?

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I've got an application that uses Spring Cache (Ehcache), but now we need to add a 2nd node (same application). Can the cache be shared between the nodes or each with their own instance but synched?

Or do I need to look at a different solution?

Thanks.

Comment: That all depends on your used cache implementation and has nothing to do with Spring Cache itself. EhCache can be clustered but I believe that is commercial product and not open source.

Comment: Take a look at hazelcast

Comment: Thanks all. I read up more on Spring Cache and as pointed out, clustering is based on the specific caching implementation. Going to look at JCS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your cache implementation - not on Spring, which only provides an abstract caching API. You are using EhCache as your caching implementation, which comes with a Terracotta server for basic clustering support and is open source. See http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.1/clustered-cache.html#clustering-concepts for more details